# How to correctly import the same namespace in two different files in Typescript

Tags: typescript, systemjs, javascript-namespaces

I'm having an issue in understanding how to make two files with the same namespace and import one into the other in Typescript.

This is the situation:

file1.ts

```
export namespace nspace {
    export class ClassA {

    }
}
```

file2.ts

```
import {nspace} from './file1';

export namespace nspace {
    export class ClassB extends nspace.ClassA {
        private z: nspace.ClassA;
    }
}
```

inside file2 i have these errors:

1) Individual declarations in merged declaration 'nspace' must be all exported or all local

2) Property 'ClassA' does not exist on type 'typeof nspace'

On top of that, ClassA is correctly found when used to declare the type of the `z` field (it even brings me to the correct file if i use "go to declaration" in my IDE)
I have tried searching the first error on the internet because i don't really understand what it means but none of the pages i found helped. I read the documentation about Declaration Merging in Typescript but i couldn't find a situation similar to mine
I don't know if this is of any help but i'm using SystemJS in my application

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, giving another name when importing worked:

file1

```
export namespace nspace {
    export class ClassA {

    }
}
```

file2

```
import * as a from './file1';

export namespace nspace {
    export class ClassB extends a.nspace.ClassA {
        private  b: a.nspace.ClassA;

    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It should be much simpler to use:

ClassA.ts

```
namespace MyApp {
    export class ClassA {
        public a: string = "classA";
    }
}
```

ClassB.ts

```
namespace MyApp {
    export class ClassB extends ClassA {
        private class_a: ClassA = new ClassA();
        private b: string = "classB";
    }
}
```

main.ts

```
namespace MyApp {
  var b = new ClassB();
  console.log(b.class_a.a) // "classA"
}
```

The compiler will recognize that you are working within the same namespace, so there is no need to `import` it, or even prefix it.

It might be necessary to add a reference to the top of the ClassB.ts file as such:

`/// <reference path="ClassA.ts" />`

Although in my setup, I haven't had to do this, the compiler seems to pick things up correctly automatically. (I use a single OutFile and the exclude directive in tsconfig.json)

Sidenote:

What I find strange in this is that you are forced to export `ClassA` for it to be discovered in my ClassB.ts. It seems impossible to keep ClassA and ClassB private to the namespace if I want to use them in Main.ts (even in private variables). It simply errors with "Can not find name..."

Comment: As far as i've seen this is common practice when using SystemJS, you need to import everything you need in your files. Or am i using it wrong? It has always worked like this for me

Comment: I'm actually very familiar with SystemJS actually - but AFAIK if your `tsconfig.json` is set correctly (using `"module": "system"`) the resulting javascript file should have the correct SystemJS import statements. Create your typescript the typescript way and let the compiler handle the environment. Try it out and take a look at what typescript compiled for you!

Comment: my tsconfig.json has "module: system" but if i don't import everything i'm going to use in a certain file it fails when i open my application on a browser. Could it be because how gulp handles the compilation? (starts from index.ts and navigates the imports). I'm using this as starting project: https://github.com/FountainJS/generator-fountain-angular1